# Information gain calculation for decision tree when choosing root node

Tags: information-theory, entropy, decision-trees

I want to know if my calculation is wrong or correct, because i got a different result when i use an online calculator.

Here is the dataset:

```
A;B;C;Class
y;y;y;group1
n;y;y;group2
y;n;n;group3
y;y;n;group3
n;y;n;group2
y;n;y;group1
n;n;n;group1
```

I am using ID3 to pick a root node. The difference appear on when i calculate the information gain when using attribute C to be the root node. my calculation on attribute A and B are aligned with the online calculator.

E(S) = -3/7 log2 3/7 - 2/7 log2 2/7 - 2/7 log2 2/7 = 1.557 (round to 3 decimal spaces)

when using attribute C as root

```
P(Y) = 4/7
P(N) = 3/7

P(Group1|Y) = 3/4
P(Group2|Y) = 1/4
P(Group3|Y) = 0/4
Entropy(Y) = -3/4 log2 3/4 - 1/4 log2 1/4 = 0.811

P(Group1|N) = 0/3
P(Group2|N) = 1/3
P(Group3|N) = 2/3
Entropy(N) = -1/3 log2 1/3 - 2/3 log2 2/3 = 0.918
```

G(C) = 1.557 - 4/7 x 0.811 - 3/7 x 0.918 = 0.700

However, when i use online calculator to check my calculation, the gain of G(C) is 0.306. I have double check my calculation, am not sure what's wrong. Could someone help to point out?

Thanks

Comment: You need to put way more effort into explaining what you're doing. Half of this is unintelligible to me.

Comment: sorry if my question seems stupid, i just started to study decision tree, I want to calculate the information gain for attribute C to be the root of the tree, but my calculation above is wrong, i want to know why

Comment: It doesn't seem stupid, it just cannot be understood without being inside your head.

Comment: Can you explain which part is "Half of this is unintelligible to me" you mean? it would be more helpful, thanks

Comment: or can you show me the right steps of choosing the root node for a decision tree with the information gain of each attribute, so i can try to see where i made the mistake, thanks

Comment: For a start, you don't introduce any of the functions you use.

Comment: ok, i thought there is only 1 way to calculate information gain, so i didnt know i need to add it, to clarify i used ID3 to calculate the information gain.